# Angular 5 calling service redundancy in components

Tags: angular, service

I have a big code redundancy in my angular 5 app.

Basically all my pages (components) have to call a service grants to check the access that the user have on the page :

```
  public grants = (): Observable<Grants> => {
    return this._http.get(this.actionUrl + '/grants', { withCredentials: true })
      .map((response: Response) => response.json() as Grants)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

What I'm doing basically now in each page is :

```
constructor(protected authService: AuthService) {
    this.authService.grants().subscribe(grants => {
      this.userAccess = grants;
      this.showComponents(grants); // Show the components that user has access to based the grants answer
    });
  }
```

The problem is that I'm doing this in every single page which I find redundant and I would like to know the best way to solve this problem.

Comment: How about inheritance - extract a common base class for all components that does this.

Comment: Yes I thought about it but how I can manage to call a function after the service finish his async call from the abstract component ?

Comment: Just override the method in the child classes, and have a no-op or abstract implementation in the parent.

Comment: What is 'page'? Considering that pages are usually implemented as routes, this is done via router guards.

Comment: @estus yes exactly I'm trying to see how I can implement my code using router guards, if you call tell me the correct way to do it using the exemple I gave above.

Comment: That is covered in the docs: https://angular.io/guide/http